# How to wait for running observable to finish on android?

Tags: android, rx-java, system.reactive, observable

I have dataModule which provides DataModel some way

```
static Single<DataModel> loadData();
```

Also there is an Activity which needs the data on start

```
public void onCreate() {
   DataModel.loadData().doOnSuccess(this::bindData)
        .subscribe()
   ...
```

Also the activity has several UI buttons with callbacks, that need the data too

```
public void onViewCreated(View v..) {
   v.findViewById(R.id..).setOnClickListener(this::updateViewX)
   v.findViewById(R.id..).setOnClickListener(this::updateViewX)
}


void updateViewX() {
   DataModel.loadData().doOnSuccess(dataModel -> /** somehow updating ui **/)
           .subscribe()
}

void updateViewY() {
   DataModel.loadData().doOnSuccess(dataModel -> /** somehow updating ui **/)
           .subscribe()
}
```

It works, but in this code snippet loads the same data  each time on button click.
What I want is:

1. to load the data **only once** in onCreate
2. Wait until it loads and only then execute callbacks (if button was pressed - callback should wait for data)

Please help me with some ideas

Answer (score 0):

```
DataModel.loadData().subscribe({dataModel -> /** somehow updating ui **/});
```

You need to subscribe using an `Observable` or an `Action` with `subscribe()` method.

Comment: I think that there is no big difference to process an event in subscribe or doOnSuccess.
Unfortunately both of them will cause execution of loadData each time user presses button.

Comment: Then you can hide buttons until data is binded. After is binded, show them. Or disable/enable them. Or you can use `combileLatest()` if you make reactive views using `RxBinding`.

Comment: What I want is pending behaviour: if button was pressed before data loading completes, the callback of the button will be delayed and executed only after successful loading of data

Comment: Thanks, I will research combineLatest